# PHP Query is correct but results don't match?

Tags: php, mysql

I only have two databases and they both run through the same select script.  The script works perfectly for one, but the other only shows the first three lines of the database and it shows them repetitively.

As I am new to PHP, I can't image why it works for one database and not the other.  I quadruple checked all my spellings and I echoed the query script just to be sure.  To make matters worse the browser isn't giving me an error as a clue.  It just shows the wrong info.

Please help. . .and thank you!

index.html (this is form...I don't think the issue is here...but I'm including it just in case...I think the issue must be down in product_list.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head><title>Databases</title></head>
        <body>
                <h1>Music Store Database</h1>
                <form method='POST' action='display.php'
                        <label>Select a table:</label>
                        <select name="tableName">
                                <option value="products">Products</option>
                                <option value="categories">Categories</option>
                        </select>
                        <p>To ADD: Enter the field values(s)  below for the record(s) you want to add.  NOTE:  Adding a record requires all appropriate field for the selected table.<p>
                        <p>To DELETE:  Enter the value for the field you are going to use to identify the desired record(s).  Then select that field from "delete record(s)" section below.</$
                                <label>ProductID</label>
                                <input type="text" name="productIDtx" value=""/></br>
                                <label>CategoryID</label>
                                <input type="text" name="categoryIDtx" value=""/></br>
                                <label>Product Code</label>
                                <input type="text" name="productCodetx" value=""/></br>
                                <label>Product Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="productNametx" value=""/></br>
                                <label>List Price</label>
                                <input type="text" name="listPricetx" value=""/></br>
                                <label>Category Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="categoryNametx" value=""/></br>
                        <p>Delete Record(s):  Select desired field below.  Don't forget to complete the information for the record in question above:</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="remove" value="productID"/>
                                <label>ProductID</label><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="remove" value="categoryID"/>
                                <label>CategoryID</label><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="remove" value="productCode"/>
                                <label>Product Code</label><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="remove" value="productName"/>
                                <label>Product Name</label><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="remove" value="listPrice"/>
                                <label>List Price</label><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="remove" value="categoryName"/>
                                <label>Category Name</label><br />
                        <p>To Retrieve Record(s): Select field(s) below you want to see from the list below.</p>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="productIDcb"/>
                                <label>ProductID</label><br />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="categoryIDcb"/>
                                <label>CategoryID</label><br />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="productCodecb"/>
                                <label>Product Code</label><br />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="productNamecb"/>
                                <label>Product Name</label><br />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="listPricecb"/>
                                <label>List Price</label><br />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="categoryNamecb"/>
                                <label>Category Name</label><br />
                        <p>Select the appropriate action based on your selection from above:</p>
                                <input type="radio" name="operation" value="retrieve"/>
                                <label>Retrieve Information</label><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="operation" value="addition"/>
                                <label>Add Information</label><br />
                                <input type="radio" name="operation" value="delete"/>
                                <label>Delete Information</label><br />
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit Request"/></p>
                </form>
       </body>
</html>
```

---

display.php (this catches the info from my form and calls the functions...still including just in case, but I imagine the issue must be with the next file.)

```
<?php
  require('database.php');

  $productIDtx = $_POST['productIDtx'];
  $categoryIDtx = $_POST['categoryIDtx'];
  $productCodetx = $_POST['productCodetx'];
  $productNametx = $_POST['productNametx'];
  $listPricetx = $_POST['listPricetx'];
  $categoryNametx = $_POST['categoryNametx'];


  if(isset($_POST['tableName']))
   {
        $table = $_POST['tableName'];
   }
  else
   {
        echo("Must select a table.<br>");
   }//endif

  if(isset($_POST['operation']))
   {
        $operation = $_POST['operation'];
   }
  else
   {
        echo("Must select an action.<br>");
        exit();
   }//endif

   if(isset($_POST['remove']))
   {
        $remove = $_POST['remove'];
   }
   else
   {
        $remove = "";
   }//endif

   if(isset($_POST['productIDcb']))
   {
        $productIDcb = $_POST['productIDcb'];
   }
   else
   {
        $productIDcb = "";
   }//endif

   if(isset($_POST['categoryIDcb']))
   {
        $categoryIDcb = $_POST['categoryIDcb'];
   }
   else
   {
        $categoryIDcb = "";
   }//endif

   if(isset($_POST['productCodecb']))
   {
        $productCodecb = $_POST['productCodecb'];
   }
 else
   {
        $productCodecb = "";
   }//endif

   if(isset($_POST['productNamecb']))
   {
        $productNamecb = $_POST['productNamecb'];
   }
   else
   {
        $productNamecb = "";
   }//endif

   if(isset($_POST['listPricecb']))
   {
        $listPricecb = $_POST['listPricecb'];
   }
   else
   {
        $listPricecb = "";
   }//endif

   if(isset($_POST['categoryNamecb']))
   {
        $categoryNamecb = $_POST['categoryNamecb'];
   }
   else
   {
        $categoryNamecb = "";
   }//endif


  if($operation == 'retrieve')
        {
                include_once('product_list.php');
                show_products($productIDcb, $categoryIDcb, $productCodecb, $productNamecb, $listPricecb, $categoryNamecb);
        }
  elseif($operation == 'addition')
        {
                include_once('addprod.php');
                add($table, $productIDtx, $categoryIDtx, $productCodetx, $productNametx, $listPricetx, $categoryNametx);
        }
  elseif($operation == 'delete')
        {
                include_once('deleteprod.php');
                delete($table, $remove, $productIDtx, $categoryIDtx, $productCodetx, $productNametx, $listPricetx, $categoryNametx);
        }
  else
        {
                echo('<p>Select an action:  Retrieve, Add, or Delete. </p>');  //this code shouldn't ever happen because $operation is tested above but I put it in here in case an errors at this point in the code.
                exit();
        }//endif

?>
```

---

product_list.php (I think the issue must be with $rSET or somewhere after because the echo of $theQuery show correct.  Yet this works for the other database.  So I am at a loss.)

```
<?php
  include('database.php');


  function show_products($productIDcb, $categoryIDcb, $productCodecb, $productNamecb, $listPricecb, $categoryNamecb)
  {
        global $db;
        $theQuery = 'select ';
        $list = "";
        if($productIDcb == "")
         {
                $theQuery == $theQuery;
         }
        else
         {
                $theQuery .= 'p.productID, ';
         }//endif

        if($categoryIDcb == "")
         {
                $theQuery == $theQuery;
         }//endif

        else
         {
                $theQuery .= 'c.categoryID, ';

         }//endif

        if($productCodecb == "")
         {
                $theQuery == $theQuery;
         }
        else
         {
                $theQuery .= 'p.productCode, ';

         }//endif

        if($productNamecb == "")
         {
                $theQuery == $theQuery;
         }
        else
         {
                 $theQuery .= 'p.productName, ';
         }//endif

        if($listPricecb == "")
         {
                $theQuery == $theQuery;
         }
        else
         {
                $theQuery .= 'p.listPrice, ';
         }//endif

        if($categoryNamecb == "")
         {
                $theQuery == $theQuery;
         }
        else
         {
                $theQuery .= 'c.categoryName, ';
         }//endif

        $theQuery .=" '' from (categories c, products p) where (c.categoryID = p.categoryID);";
        echo($theQuery);
        echo('<br>');

        //***I THINK THE ISSUE MUST BE SOMEWHERE AFTER THIS***

        $rSet = $db -> query($theQuery);
        foreach($rSet AS $results)
          {
              $list .=' '.$results[0];
                if(isset($results[1]))
                {
                   $list .=' '.$results[1];
                }
                if(isset($results[2]))
                {
                   $list .=' '.$results[2];
                }
                if(isset($results[3]))
                {
                   $list .=' '.$results[3];
                }
                if(isset($products[4]))
                {
                   $list .=' '.$results[4];
                }
              $list .="<br>";
          }//end foreach
        echo($list);
        echo('<br>');
        echo('<a href="index.html">Music Store Database</a>');

}//end function
?>
```

---

products database query (this one works)

select p.productID, c.categoryID, p.productCode, p.productName, p.listPrice, '' from (categories c, products p) where (c.categoryID = p.categoryID);

1 1 strat Fender Stratocaster

2 1 les_paul Gibson Les Paul

3 1 sg Gibson SG

4 1 fg700s Yamaha FG700S

5 1 washburn Washburn D10S

6 1 rodriguez Rodriguez Caballero 11

7 2 precision Fender Precision

8 2 hofner Hofner Icon

9 3 ludwig Ludwig 5-piece Drum Set with Cymbals

10 3 tama Tama 5-Piece Drum Set with Cymbals

---

categories database query (the query looks correct but the data is wrong)

select c.categoryID, c.categoryName, '' from (categories c, products p) where (c.categoryID = p.categoryID);

1 Guitars

1 Guitars

1 Guitars

1 Guitars

1 Guitars

1 Guitars

2 Basses

2 Basses

3 Drums

3 Drums

it should list the following

1 Guitars

2 Basses

3 Drums

11 test

15 test

20 test

33 test33

40 test

(note:  the tests were from when I was testing the add function - in case you were wondering).

Comment: Can you show the contents of the database.php file?

Comment: Can you echo out the SQL you're generating both for a query that works how you want, and for one of the ones that fails?

Comment: I added a copy of the database directly from mysql, but it looks rather messy.  Let me see if I can get it another way.  I'll also get the two statements to show. Thank you and just one moment.

Comment: do `print_r($rSet)` and temme what you get..

Comment: @user3025217 - I think you might need to do an explicit JOIN in your query. If you try running the query you're getting right in the database, does it also produce the same same results? What if you try `SELECT categoryID, categoryName FROM categories c INNER JOIN products p ON c.categoryID=p.categoryID`?

Comment: I put this after $rSet = $db -> query($theQuery);  Let me know if that's ok.

Comment: I got the same wrong results as before but it showed this above  PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => select c.categoryID, c.categoryName, '' from (categories c, products p) where (c.categoryID = p.categoryID); )

Comment: I tried the INNER JOIN as well.  Still getting odd results from categories database.  Here's the result of the print_r($rSet) when setup with an INNER JOIN:   PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => select c.categoryID, c.categoryName, '' from categories c INNER JOIN products p ON c.categoryID = p.categoryID; )

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this.  This seems so odd and I don't have enough PHP knowledge to being to understand why it doesn't pull the same from both databases.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT`? I think you're possibly getting duplicated because you have products in multiple categories, and nothing in there to eliminate duplicated rows, so a SELECT DISTINCT will only show unique rows.

Comment: WHEW!  Thank you so MUCH!  So cool!  Haven't used that one yet.  It did eliminate the duplicates.   I just realized the rest of the categories won't show up unless they are used in the products database because of (c.categoriesID = p.categoryID).  Crap!  I'll try the inner join again to see if that get's around this.

Comment: @user3025217 - once you've figured the rest of it out, feel free to add an answer with what you've done, and accept it when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone that commented above to get me to this point.  As andrewsi pointed out, the SELECT DISTINCT code did fix the issue of repeats, but the entire categories table would not show due to (c.categoryID = p.categoryID).  So I added and if else statement to handle the two situations and that also eliminated the need for DISTINCT.  Here's the code that fixed it.

```
if($theQuery == 'select c.categoryID, c.categoryName, ')
        {
                $theQuery = "";
                $theQuery = "select * from categories;";
        }
        else
        {
                $theQuery .=" '' from (categories c, products p) WHERE (c.categoryID = p.categoryID);";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will lead to cartesian product, which returns you duplicate results.Try using `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN`.

```
SELECT categoryID, categoryName
FROM categories c
CROSS JOIN products p
WHERE (c.categoryID = p.categoryID)
```

Comment: I'll try that next time. . .thanks. . .for now I just used an if statement to handle the situation.